# finding the rank of $f$

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, linear-transformations

> Let $f$ be a function and $\mathbb{F}$ some field, with
> $$
> f: \mathbb{F}^{2020 \times 2020} \to \mathbb{F}^{2020 \times 2020}, X \mapsto X - X^T
> $$
>
> What rank does $f$ have?

I know that: rank of $f \Leftrightarrow$ rank of $M$, where M is the transformation matrix. But I don't know how to get to $M$ in order to check its rank.
Another thing I observed is that $f$ can't have full rank since every symmetric matrix is mapped to $0$. Don't know if thats helpful.

Comment: It looks like the kernel of this map is a familiar space. Did you try the rank-nullity theorem?

Comment: So I have to use $dim(V) - dim(kernel(f)) = dim(f)$, where the $dim(V) = 2020$. So I just have to find the $dim(kernel(f))$?

Comment: $\dim(V)=2020\times2020$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comments, it suffices to determine $\dim \ker f$. Of course, we see that $f(X) = 0$ if and only if $X = X^T$, which is to say that $X$ is symmetric.

In order to determine the dimension of the space of symmetric matrices, I find that it is easiest to determine the number of "degrees of freedom" we have within the space, i.e. the number of parameters necessary to completely specify an element of the space.

In generating an arbitrary symmetric matrix, we may freely choose the entries on or above the diagonal; once we have done this, we have completely specified a symmetric matrix.  For instance, if I select
$$
\pmatrix{1&2&3\\?&-1&4\\?&?&7},
$$
then the only symmetric matrix I could be referring to is
$$
\pmatrix{1&2&3\\2&-1&4\\3&4&7}.
$$
The values that I specified are the first value from first column, the first two from the second column, the first three from the third, and so forth. In other words, the total number of "coordinates" required to specify a symmetric matrix is
$$
1 + 2 + \cdots + 2019 + 2020 = \frac{2020(2020 + 1)}{2}.
$$
Thus, we have $\dim \ker f$. The rank is thus $2020^2 - \dim \ker f$, which is to say
$$
2020^2 - \frac{2020(2020 + 1)}{2} = \frac{2 \cdot 2020^2 - 2020^2 - 2020}{2}
\\
= \frac{2020^2 - 2020}{2} = \frac{2020(2020-1)}{2} \\
= 1010\cdot 2019 = 2039190.
$$

---

We could also have directly determined the dimension of the image. Note that the image of $f$ consists of all skew-symmetric matrices. To see this, note that $f(X)^T = f(X)$, and that for any $Y$ such that $Y = -Y^T$, we have $f(X) = Y$ when we select $X = Y/2$.

From there, we can count the dimension of the set of skew-symmetric matrices by noting that it suffices to specify the entries above the diagonal (the entries along the diagonal must be $0$).